Auto PY to EXE two py files into 1exe
I'm trying to do a discord bot for me and my friends, but we can't host it on a server so I was thinking to make an exe so I did that and I said to myself it would be nice to have a graphical interface so I did another file with the interface and I tried to make them merge with this and it won't work, so want i want to do is take the 2 files in python and have 1 exe and I used a custom font that I put in the same directory could anyone help me ?
I tried to put first the code of the bot in main file and the UI in additional and next the opposite

I'd recommend you to use pyinstaller: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/index.html
You can use this package to convert a python file into an executable file (.exe). By using arguments you can add multiple source files (.py) and resource files (pictures, data, etc...)
Here is the command I used for one of my projects:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "C:/Documents/dev/project/files/favicon.ico" --name "project" --hide-console "hide-early" --add-data "C:/Documents/dev/project/GUI.py;." --add-data "C:/Documents/dev/project/files;files/" "C:/Documents/dev/project/main.py"


i tried to do what you said so this : pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "E:/Docs/BotDiscord/King of dices/dé-3.ico" --name "King of dices" --hide-console "hide-early" --add-data "E:/Docs/BotDiscord/King of dices/UI.py" "E:/Docs/BotDiscord/King of dices/King of dices.py"
but i got an error : pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: Wrong syntax, should be --add-data=SOURCE:DEST

It's because when adding a file or a folder into your exe file, you should specify where it should be added. That's why the --add-data argument asks you a destination in the following format, as a relative path: --add-data=SOURCE:DEST
Try out this one:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "E:/Docs/BotDiscord/King of dices/dé-3.ico" --name "King of dices" --hide-console "hide-early" --add-data "E:/Docs/BotDiscord/King of dices/UI.py:." "E:/Docs/BotDiscord/King of dices/King of dices.py"
I added a colon and a dot after UI.py so that your file stays right next the main.

okay so now it accepts to do the exports but it won't show up the ui that i did and to close it i need to go to the task manager, i tried to switch --hide-console "hide-early" by --noconsole and my pc and the exporter said wtf this is a virus and stopped me to doing this if you want the code of my ui tell me and i send it
